# Getting Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php

I get the error in the subject. Also I spent ages on google and found dozens of resources having the same error, but still I can't figure out what the issue is.
This is my code:

```
<?php
if(empty(trim($_POST["user"])) || empty(trim($_POST["text"]))) {
    echo "no luck";
  }
?>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /var/www/test.php on on line 2

Comment: can you please explain little it more? [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YDgKn)

Comment: Depending on PHP version `empty()` expects a variable reference, not an expression / function result. Use `!strlen` alternatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to a manual, you will see

> Determine whether a **variable** is considered to be empty.

The result of `trim` passed to `empty` is **not** a variable.

So your options are:

```
$user = trim($_POST['user']);
if (!empty($user)) {   }
```

Or php5.5, in which

> `empty()` now supports expressions